# How to filter out search results in LinkedIn sales navigator

Tags: linkedin

I would like to filter out LinkedIn sales navigator search results to exclude people to whom I already sent connection proposal, but I can't achieve that. I don't whether this is possible but maybe someone of you already did it?

I have 1500 pending invites and would not like to see these in my search results again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is currently not possible. You can only filter out "Viewed" people, which means the people whose profile pages you have already visited.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with the recent additions of filters on Sales Navigator.
You will find it in the Lead Filter > Workflow > People you interacted with > Remove contacted people

Comment: "Remove contacted people" won't work. It only has "Viewed Profile" or "Messaged". It doesn't have a filter for "Invites Sent" I wish it did - it would be perfect.